# Array and date format issue

Tags: java, servlets

I am a beginer in jquery and java.I have two string variables and a string array.I passed these 3 to a java servlet using a post request from javascript.Below is the code:

```
var stDate= $('#drpstart').jqxDateTimeInput('getText');
var edDate= $('#drpend').jqxDateTimeInput('getText');
var items = $("#target").jqxListBox('getItems');
var itemsid=[];
$("#jqxWidget").html('');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    itemsid[i]=items[i].value;
}
$.post('ActionItem',
{startdt:stDate,enddt:edDate,item:itemsid},function(responseJson) {

                });
```

Then I access these variables and array at servlet side:

```
String starts=request.getParameter("startdt");
    String ends=request.getParameter("enddt");
    String[] myArray =request.getParameterValues("item");
    if (myArray != null ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
           System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        }
      }
    else {
        System.out.println("null value");
      }
```

but the myarray is geting a null value.How to get the values correctly to myarray?
Also my database table StockRegisterHeader contain field 'Date' with Date as datatype,so i converted the string variables starts and ends to Date format as below

```
SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date startg = from.parse(starts);       // 01/02/2014
    Date endg = from.parse(ends);
```

Now I need to select data from 4 tables within this date range. I wrote the query as below:

```
String ss="SELECT Items.ParentID,Items.Name ,StockRegisterHeader.MovementType,
StockRegisterHeader.Date, UOM.Name,StockRegisterDetails.Quantity,
StockRegisterDetails.Rate from  Items,StockRegisterHeader,UOM,StockRegisterDetails
where Items.ID = StockRegisterDetails.ItemID and
StockRegisterDetails.StockRegisterHeaderID = StockRegisterHeader.Id and
StockRegisterDetails.UOMID = UOM.ID and StockRegisterHeader.Date between '"+startg+"'
and '"+endg+"'";
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(ss);
```

But the resultset object rs is showing null even if the database contain the requested data.I think this may be due to the date format. How to solve these two issues? I am using mysql database. Please help me.

Comment: 1/ explicit joins 2/ preparedStatement, you should do some research on both topic

Comment: You need to use Same SimpleDateFormat for start and end then in query also use To_char(Date) method to produce same format and then compare

Comment: preparestatement is not considerable in my program.because later i need to change the select query according to the myarray values.That is i need to query using loops.I think preparedStatements are not effective when loops come

Comment: @user3231725 to retrieve from database we use `while(rs.next()){....}`  but you have not shown the code

Comment: @Naren Do you mean To_char(StockRegisterHeader.Date) in my query?

Comment: @user3231725, conform that itemsid is not null by using alert or log to console?

Comment: @JqueryLearner I have used while(rs.next()){...} method and check the status of resultset object rs,and its showing null.I think the issue is in the date format

Comment: @Rembo itemsid is not null when i passed it from javascript to servlet.The issue comes when i receive it in the servlet end

Comment: @user3231725 what do you mean by `check the status of resultset object rs,and its showing null` and how do you do it?Show the codes

Comment: @user3231725 did you set Accept and ContentType to application/json before AJAX post?

Comment: @JqueryLearner while(rs.next()){
   System.out.println("ok");
   
  }  when i run the code console is showing none.Also i checked the query in mysql workbench using the converted date format(ie,like 'Sat Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 2014') getting the result as zero rows returned.but if i give the datevalue like '2014-02-01' then i get get the requested data

Comment: @user3231725 That means your resultset is empty and hence rs.next() returns false so control is not going to while loop.Check the query again

Comment: @Rembo no i just passed the two variables and the array as arguments with the post request as show in above.And i have received the value for the two variable at server side,but not getting the value for the array

Comment: ok now the query works fine when i converted the date variables to string with format as 'yyyy-MM-dd'.But still the array issue is not solved.How to get the array values that i pased from the javascript in a jsp page to servlet?

Comment: anybody is here to solve this array issue??

Comment: finally i got my answer i just modified the array usage as follows String myArray[] =request.getParameterValues("item[]");  now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
String[] myArray =request.getParameterValues("item");
```

to

```
String[] myArray =request.getParameterValues("item[]"); //brackets must be specified to retrive array value
```